# How to unit test flink timers using mockito

Tags: unit-testing, timer, mockito, apache-flink

I have a process funtion, im using mockito for unit testing.

```
class SampleProcessFunction : KeyedProcessFunction<String, String, String>() {{
        override fun processElement(dm: String, ctx: Context, out: Collector<String>) {
            var retrieveState = state.value()
            // schedule the next timer  from the current event time
            ctx.timerService().registerEventTimeTimer(ctx.timestamp() + 3000)
        } 
    
     override fun onTimer(scheduledTimer: Long, ctx: OnTimerContext?, out: Collector<String>) {
            val retrieveState = state.value()
    
            if(scheduledTimer == (ctx.timestamp()+3000)) {
                         out.collect(presenceEvent)
            }
        }
}
```

I wanted to unit test the process function using mockito

```
 internal class PresenceDetectionProcessFunctionTest {
    
        private lateinit var out: Collector<String>
        private lateinit var mockPresenceState: ValueState<Presence>
    
    
        @BeforeEach
        fun setUp() {
            SampleProcessFunction = SampleProcessFunction()
            out = mock(Collector::class.java) as Collector<PresenceEvent>
            val mockRunTimeContext = mock(RuntimeContext::class.java)
            mockSampleState = mock(ValueState::class.java) as ValueState<SampleState>
           
    
            whenever(mockRunTimeContext.getState(ValueStateDescriptor("sample-state", 
             Sample::class.java))).thenReturn(mockSampleState)      
            
             sampleProcessFunction.runtimeContext = mockRunTimeContext
            sampleProcessFunction.open(Configuration())
        }
    
    @Test
    fun `test sample process function`() {
       
        sampleProcessFunction.processElement("Hellp, context, out)
        Mockito.verify(mockPresenceState, times(1)).update(result.capture())
       }
```

How do we test the timer here, in my process fun i have register the event timer, but when I debug throws NPE at `ctx.timerService().registerEventTimeTimer(ctx.timestamp() + 3000)` in sample  process function as I did not setup any test configuration for timers in my test. How do we test the flink timer functionality here? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use Flink's test harnesses, as [described in the documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/testing.html#unit-testing-stateful-or-timely-udfs--custom-operators).

This involves:

- adding some dependencies to your build
- instantiating a test harness with the appropriate operator
- using the test harness in some tests

---

Here's an example:

```java
public class MyKeyedProcessFunctionTest {
    private OneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness<Long, Long> testHarness;

    @Before
    public void setupTestHarness() throws Exception {
        testHarness = new OneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness<>(new KeyedProcessOperator<>(new MyProcessFunction()));
        testHarness.open();
    }

    @Test
    public void testingStatefulFunction() throws Exception {
        assertThat(testHarness.numKeyedStateEntries(), is(0));
        testHarness.setProcessingTime(0L);
        
        // state gets created
        testHarness.processElement(2L, 100L);
        assertThat(testHarness.numKeyedStateEntries(), is(not(0)));
        
        // state is eventually cleared
        testHarness.setProcessingTime(3600000L);
        assertThat(testHarness.numKeyedStateEntries(), is(0));
    }

    @Test
    public void testTimelyOperator() throws Exception {
    
        // setup initial conditions
        testHarness.processWatermark(0L);
        assertThat(testHarness.numEventTimeTimers(), is(0));
    
        // send in some data
        testHarness.processElement(3L, 100L);
    
        // verify timer
        assertThat(testHarness.numEventTimeTimers(), is(1));
    
        // fire timer
        testHarness.processWatermark(20);
        assertThat(testHarness.numEventTimeTimers(), is(0));
    
        // verify results
        assertThat(testHarness.getOutput(), containsInExactlyThisOrder(3L));
        assertThat(testHarness.getSideOutput(new OutputTag<>("invalidRecords")), hasSize(0))
    }
}
```